# less の z でスクロールする行数を確認したい

Tags: linux

less で何度も (100z などによって) スクロール行数を変更していると、現在のスクロール行数が分からなくなることがあります。
現在のスクロール行数を知る方法はないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_z` で現在の window size が表示されます。..

Answer (score 1):

あらかじめ `less -N ファイル名` で起動しておくと行数が表示されます
すでに起動中の場合 `-N` を入力して行数が表示できます
消したくなったら `-n` を入力して消せます

また、ヘルプには `=`, `ctrl + g` または `:f` で現在のファイル名が出ると書かれていますが
このとき現在表示中の行数も表示されるように見えます